# Find all real numbers a and b for which the linear system has (i) no solutions (ii) infinitely many solutions and (iii)exactly one solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am stuck with this linear system:

\begin{cases}
x_1 + x_3 = 0 \\
ax_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 = 0 \\
3x_1 + 4x_2 + bx_3 = 2
\end{cases}

My augmented matrix so far looks like this:
R2- aR1
R3- 3R1
and then R3-4R2

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 &  0 \\
0 & 1 & 2-a & 0  \\
0 & 0 & b-3-8-4a & 2
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! There's an error: the last row show be $\;0\quad 0\quad b-11 \color{red}+4a\quad 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: From the first equation we get
$$x_3=-x_1$$ so we can write

$$ax_1+x_2-2x_1=0$$
and

$$3x_1+4x_2-bx_1=2$$

Now we will eliminate $$x_2=2x_1-ax_1$$
so we will get

$$3x_1+4(2x_1-ax_1)-bx_1=2$$ or

$$x_1(11-4a-b)=2$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81598/discussion-on-answer-by-dr-sonnhard-graubner-find-all-real-numbers-a-and-b-for).